# CentOS 7 yum "database is locked"

Tags: centos7, yum, linux-vserver

Today I wanted to install another PHP-Extension to my virtual server with "yum install php-mbstring" and ran into an error. It said: "database is locked". I already searched alot in Google but it still doesn't works. Thats the reason I'm currently writing this topic. The error happens everytime I want to install an package.

I'm using CentOS 7.

Oh and sorry for my absolutely bad english, I'm from germany.

I hope someone can help me.

Edit: Screenshot of the error: http://prntscr.com/v64nmr

~Paul

Comment: Propably a leftovers of interrupted install/update attempts. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037629/yum-database-is-locked#51770771

Answer (score 0):

check this [post](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=66998) from centos forum . This post looks similar to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking time, I tried everything they said but it didn't helped :(